# Integrating $\int\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin x \cos x}dx$. The substitution $u=\sin x\cos x$ leads to an incorrect answer.

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem:

[image]

In the first case I used a substitution $u = \sin x\cos x$ and proceeded with my calculations, which led to an incorrect answer.
In the second case I used a different substitution, which led to a correct answer.

My question is: what is wrong with $u = \sin x\cos x$?

Comment: They're both fine. Remember with integration, an antiderivative gives a family of functions that are the "same" up to a constant. Hint: log rules.

Comment: Note $$C + \log ax= \underbrace{C + \log a}_{C'} + \log x = C' + \log x$$

Comment: $\ln |\sin 2x| = \ln|\sin x\cos x| + \ln |2|.$ The difference between the two answers lies in the constant of integration.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions since it is searchable and pictures are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question doesn’t remain unanswered:

$\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin 2x$, so the results only differ by an additive constant $\log2$, so there’s no discrepancy if you use different variable names for the two integration constants.